# Nestjs Nested array of object dynamically key

Tags: nestjs, nest

How create a structure dto for this structure of data and CRUD operation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create user.entity.ts. You didnt specify to what db you use, but ı just think you are using mongodb and in mongodb you can just create models like that.
then

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Document } from "mongoose";

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId})
  id: string;

  @Prop({maxlength:50})
  name: string;
  
  @Prop()
  phone: string;

  ...
}


export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Comment: But the key of value is autogenerate which is the structure best for this (i use class-validator)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use index for some **dynamic** fields:

```
[index: string]: {
...fields
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a structure in dto or class validator which are the ones I use?

Comment: ```
export class UserInfo {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    "_id": string;

    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    "name": string;
    // ...
}

export class UserDto {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    [index: string]: UserInfo
}
```